# Form submit only one value with AJAX passing form data to PHP in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to pass a single value from my form to my php in the same page. It´s probably not an option to create another .php file and take the code there since there´s a lot going on.
This is the part of the code I need to fix, currently it only works when the code is on another file, since the $_POST is not messing around with other parts of the code. Specifically I need to manage to pass the 'client' or the 'empre' from the form alone to the php.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

 $(function() {

 if($(".cliente").click(function() {

    var name = $("#client").val();
    var dataString = 'client='+ name;

}))else if($(".empresa").click(function() {

    var name = $("#empre").val();
    var dataString = 'empre='+ name;
}));

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: dataString});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <input name="client" type="text"><br>
  <input class="cliente" type="submit" value="Buscar cliente"/><br>
  <input name="empre" type="text"><br>
  <input class="empresa" type="submit" value="Buscar empresa"/><br>
  </form>

  //PHP HERE

  //HTML AGAIN
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP (same page, just separating for readability)

```
   if(isset($_POST['empre'])){

       //DB QUERY
   }
   elseif(isset($_POST['client'])){

       //DB QUERY

   }
```

Comment: Your `$.ajax` is invalid. It's missing `url` and `data` should be `data: {data: someValue}`

Comment: Change the input type="submit" to input type="button" otherwise the form will be submitted with GET also.

Comment: @MilanChheda Can I place in url the same page? I figured if there was no url the default would be the one i´m in.

Comment: @Adder This seems like a good idea, will try it out. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use separate forms to process the data? (Your PHP logic mentioned will work with this proposed solution)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".cliente").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Going to post data for client, check the console log now');
    $.ajax({
     url: $('form[name="client"]').attr('action'),
      type: "POST",
      data: $('form[name="client"]').serialize(),
      success: function(data){
       console.log(data);
      },
      failure: function(error){}
    });
  });
  $(".empresa").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Going to post data for empre, check the console log now');
    $.ajax({
     url: $('form[name="empre"]').attr('action'),
      type: "POST",
      data: $('form[name="empre"]').serialize(),
      success: function(data){
       console.log(data);
      },
      failure: function(error){}
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="client" action="https://someurl.com/fileto.php">
  <input name="client" type="text"  value="some value"><br>
  <input class="cliente" type="submit" value="Buscar cliente"/>
</form>
<form name="empre" action="https://someurl.com/fileto.php">
  <input name="empre" type="text" value="some value"><br>
  <input class="empresa" type="submit" value="Buscar empresa"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Why use separated why you can merge? Please explain the reason behind separating them.

Comment: I can´t manage to make it work... It does nothing when I click the client submit. The url changes to this: http://url?client=8

Comment: you will probably have to set your own URL @JuanjoC, I just gave this as an example as your original posted code was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @MilanChheda he shouldn't merge the fields of the form as he is trying to send different sets of data. This method the HTML layout using 2 forms will handle the separation of data and not the javascript. The proposed method isn't per say the ONLY method of doing it, it is just a proposed method to keep the code a bit cleaner.

Comment: @SchalkKeun even with my own url I get the same problem. The php wont accept the $_POST when its located in the same page. But ty for your answer.

Comment: @JuanjoC if you want to post it to the same page, why even bother using AJAX? Why not just do a normal HTML post via your form and submit the data and then handle it on the page load? AJAX is meant to do process requests behind the scenes without having a page refresh.

Comment: @SchalkKeun Because I need to do multiple callbacks from the html to the php, and then call my DB in the php. So I wanted to have a way to do this without needing to refresh the page each time.

Comment: You will have to separate your PHP from your HTML, you can't have it all on one page then.

See my updated answer with link to JSFiddle

Comment: @SchalkKeun Thank you for your help, I think it might not be possible then.

Comment: @JuanjoC it is possible, but it will be icky! You shouldn't really ever mix HTML and PHP in one page, especially if your PHP code is going to process data.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine and send it in same AJAX call as below, and in PHP you can do:

```
$parameters = json_decode($_POST['params']);
```

`$parameters` would have all the variables sent in that AJAX call.

I would recommend, not to use same page for your AJAX. You should keep it in separate file. That would make code much cleaner, lighter, readable and easy-to-tweak.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".cliente, .empresa").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var paramsToSend = {};
    if ($(this).hasClass('client'))
      paramsToSend['client'] = $('form[name="client"]').serialize();
    else
      paramsToSend['empre'] = $('form[name="client"]').serialize()
    $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php' //assuming this is index.php (same page)
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        params: JSON.stringify(paramsToSend)
      },
      success: function(data) {},
      failure: function(error) {}
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="client">
  <input name="client" type="text" value="some value"><br>
  <input class="cliente" type="submit" value="Buscar cliente" />
</form>
<form name="empre">
  <input name="empre" type="text" value="some value"><br>
  <input class="empresa" type="submit" value="Buscar empresa" />
</form>

//PHP HERE //HTML AGAIN
```

Comment: I´m getting this: "Notice: Undefined index: params". Doesn´t seem to be reaching the php.

Comment: Did you check the console? Did it had AJAX request and payload?

Comment: Yeah I get no console log, and it´s trying to connect to ajax but it gets no response I think. Someone in the comments said it might not be possible to archieve what i´m looking for, so maybe thats why.